# How to remove search Label from Datatable?

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I want to remove Search Label from `Datatable (V1.10.10)`. Only want to use "Placeholder" I am using this but not working.

```
language: {
  url: languages['{{ app()->getLocale() }}'],
  search: ' ',
  searchPlaceholder: 'Search...'
}
```

Placeholder is working here. But label is still remaining!

If it is not possible then I want to know how to catch it with CSS or jQuery??

```
<div id="datatablePermissionID_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>
    "Search:"
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
  </label>
</div>
```

I got it from Browser Inspect.

Comment: Seems working fine to me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7emv1j2/)

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for me!!